# How can I use threading to 'tick' a timer to be accessed by other threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, touch

When the user does something (touch on a StackPanel, in this case), I need to begin a timer of some sort (probably DispatcherTimer as I'm working in WPF) and if another touch happens again within a certain amount of time then I'll call a method. As you can probably guess - this is to implement a double-tap functionality.

I'm assuming the best way to achieve this is through using threads (i.e. a child thread to increment a timespan which can be checked by the Main thread any time the StackPanel is touched again?)

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to start another thread to do this.

Just take a timestamp of when the first tap happened and use this. You can then calculate the timespan by subtracting this time from the current time:

```
private DateTime _lastTap;
public void TapHandler()
{
  DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
  TimeSpan span = now - lastTap;
  _lastTap = now;
  if (span < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) {...}
}
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @DannyVarod, you can use a `Stopwatch` to achieve the same result (but with more accurate timing):

```
private Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
public void TapHandler()
{
  TimeSpan elapsed = _stopwatch.Elapsed;
  _stopwatch.Restart();
  if (elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) {...}
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Spot on. Must be too early in the morning for me. Give me 10 mins and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer (without the code sample though).

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (span < TimeSpan.Seconds(1)) {...} ? Also, I'm not able to use TimeSpan.Seconds. The code's easily adapted though, I've got it working.

Comment: You should use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch instead of DateTime.UtcNow if you want accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to stick with `DispatcherTimer` as you first pointed out, as this will ensure you don't need to do any thread marshalling on tick. If you explictly need accuracy and/or background threads, please see the `System.Timers.Timer` class and `System.Threading.Timer` class.

A code example which allows differentiation between Single and Double clicks can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (Windows Forms specific, however the principle is the same). Alternatively, please see this example using DispatcherTimer taken from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971459/wpf-button-single-click-double-click-problem)

```
   private static DispatcherTimer clickTimer = 
        new DispatcherTimer(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime), 
            DispatcherPriority.Background, 
            mouseWaitTimer_Tick, 
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);

    private void Button_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the timer from ticking.
        myClickWaitTimer.Stop();

        Trace.WriteLine("Double Click");
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myClickWaitTimer.Start();
    }

    private static void mouseWaitTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myClickWaitTimer.Stop();

        // Handle Single Click Actions
        Trace.WriteLine("Single Click");
    }
```