# Capturing double-tap touch on multi-touch screen

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I've posted another question of how to 'manually' capture a double-tap by monitoring a timespan between touches on a TouchDown event, but it's quite buggy. Does anyone know of a standard Microsoft way/event of capturing double-tap on a multi-touch screen?

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Comment: did you try the timer implementation I posted? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9000217/303612

Comment: Yes I tried this. The problem was that I was opening a window on Double-Tap, but this window was being hidden. I sort of used your concept and incorporated a .Activate() method call and it's all sorted. thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 11):

I check the combination of the tap location and a stopwatch, and it works perfect!

```
private readonly Stopwatch _doubleTapStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
private Point _lastTapLocation;

public event EventHandler DoubleTouchDown;

protected virtual void OnDoubleTouchDown()
{
    if (DoubleTouchDown != null)
        DoubleTouchDown(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private bool IsDoubleTap(TouchEventArgs e)
{
    Point currentTapPosition = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;
    bool tapsAreCloseInDistance = currentTapPosition.GetDistanceTo(_lastTapLocation) < 40;
    _lastTapLocation = currentTapPosition;

    TimeSpan elapsed = _doubleTapStopwatch.Elapsed;
    _doubleTapStopwatch.Restart();
    bool tapsAreCloseInTime = (elapsed != TimeSpan.Zero && elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7));

    return tapsAreCloseInDistance && tapsAreCloseInTime;
}

private void OnPreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsDoubleTap(e))
        OnDoubleTouchDown();
}
```

It checks in the PreviewTouchDown whether or not it's an DoubleTap.

Comment: I Couldn't find `GetDistanceTo` under `System.Windows.Point`, so I've used [this](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/How_to_get_distance_between_two_points)

Comment: I also couldn't find `GetDistance` used `Math.Abs(Point.Subtract(currentTapPosition, _lastTapLocation).Length) < 40;`

Answer (score 3):

Jowens answer helped me a lot (if my reputation would let me, I´ll upvote it ;))
BUT I had to adjust it, so it worked with double taps only. The original code does consider any tap above 2 to be a double tap. Changing the _lastTapLocation to a nullable and resetting it when it´s a double tap helped.

```
private Point? _lastTapLocation;

private bool IsDoubleTap(TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentTapPosition = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;
        bool tapsAreCloseInDistance = false;
        if (_lastTapLocation != null)
        {
            tapsAreCloseInDistance = GetDistanceBetweenPoints(currentTapPosition, (Point)_lastTapLocation) < 70;
        }
        _lastTapLocation = currentTapPosition;

        TimeSpan elapsed = _doubleTapStopwatch.Elapsed;
        _doubleTapStopwatch.Restart();
        bool tapsAreCloseInTime = (elapsed != TimeSpan.Zero && elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7));

        if (tapsAreCloseInTime && tapsAreCloseInDistance)
        {
            _lastTapLocation = null;
        }
        return tapsAreCloseInDistance && tapsAreCloseInTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think utilizing the StylusSystemGesture event is more appropriate. 
Here my code.

```
    public static class ext
{
private static Point? _lastTapLocation;
        private static readonly Stopwatch _DoubleTapStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        public static bool IsDoubleTap(this StylusSystemGestureEventArgs e, IInputElement iInputElement)
        {
            Point currentTapPosition = e.GetPosition(iInputElement);
            bool tapsAreCloseInDistance = false;
            if (_lastTapLocation != null)
            {
                tapsAreCloseInDistance = GetDistanceBetweenPoints(currentTapPosition, (Point)_lastTapLocation) < 70;
            }
            _lastTapLocation = currentTapPosition;

            TimeSpan elapsed = _DoubleTapStopwatch.Elapsed;
            _DoubleTapStopwatch.Restart();
            bool tapsAreCloseInTime = (elapsed != TimeSpan.Zero && elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7));

            if (tapsAreCloseInTime && tapsAreCloseInDistance)
            {
                _lastTapLocation = null;
            }
            return tapsAreCloseInDistance && tapsAreCloseInTime;
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
 private void UIElement_OnStylusSystemGesture(object sender, StylusSystemGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SystemGesture == SystemGesture.Tap)
        {
            if (e.IsDoubleTap(sender as IInputElement))
            {
               // Do your stuff here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Andreas' answer, You may also be able to remove the Stopwatch-related code.

[StylusSystemGestureEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylussystemgestureeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) also comes with a [Timestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputeventargs.timestamp(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which I believe counts in milliseconds.

So instead of using the Stopwatch to calculate from the TimeSpan, add an `int _lastTimestamp` field and subtract the timestamps.

```
public static class ext
{
    private static Point? _lastTapLocation;

    // Stopwatch changed to int
    private int _lastTimestamp = 0;

    public static bool IsDoubleTap(this StylusSystemGestureEventArgs e, IInputElement iInputElement)
    {
        Point currentTapPosition = e.GetPosition(iInputElement);
        bool tapsAreCloseInDistance = false;
        if (_lastTapLocation != null)
        {
            tapsAreCloseInDistance = GetDistanceBetweenPoints(currentTapPosition, (Point)_lastTapLocation) < 70;
        }
        _lastTapLocation = currentTapPosition;

        // This replaces the previous TimeSpan calculation
        bool tapsAreCloseInTime = ((e.Timestamp - _lastTimestamp) < 700);

        if (tapsAreCloseInTime && tapsAreCloseInDistance)
        {
            _lastTapLocation = null;
        }

        _lastTimestamp = e.Timestamp;

        return tapsAreCloseInDistance && tapsAreCloseInTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to apply the `e.Timestamp to _lastTimestamp` after compare!