# Canvas with shape on it - MouseUp events fire on both of them when I click shape

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have canvas with ellipse like this:

```
<Canvas 
     Name="c1" 
     Background="White" 
     MouseUp="c1_MouseUp">
        <Ellipse 
              Width="138" 
              Height="143" 
              Fill="Chocolate" 
              MouseUp="Ellipse_MouseUp">
        </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

With event handlers like this:

```
    private void Ellipse_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ellipse click");
    }

    private void c1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Canvas click");
    }
```

Both events fire when I click on ellipse.
I want only `Ellipse_MouseUp` to fire.

Are there any simple methods to make it work as I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the one you want to process e.Handled = True; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.aspx

EDIT as an example the following should work:

```
void Ellipse_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = True;
    MessageBox.Show("Ellipse click");
}
```

Comment: Related post with more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971459/wpf-button-single-click-double-click-problem

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out before you added code, but it will be useful for others :)