# WPF: Figuring out whether a MouseBinding is a single click or double click

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

Im using Mousebindings in my view to listen to user clicks like this:

```
<Path.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DoubleLeftClickProj}" />
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding SingleLeftClick}"/>
</Path.InputBindings>
```

I only need one of the mouse gestures at a time. So if I double click on my application I want to ignore the single left click mousebinding. Possibly like waiting 1-2sec after the initial mouseclick then decided which should be called. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: No simple way available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working the following way (I used a Button to test it, you'll have to adapt it).

1. Use Event Handlers

   ```
   <Button MouseDoubleClick="Button_MouseDoubleClick" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
   ```
2. store the DataContext in a static variable

   ```
   private static object context;
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = new ViewModel();
       context = DataContext;
   }
   ```
3. Adapt this code (I mainly got it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/971676/4792869)

   ```
   private static DispatcherTimer myClickWaitTimer =
   new DispatcherTimer(
       new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1),
       DispatcherPriority.Background,
       mouseWaitTimer_Tick,
       Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);

   private void Button_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       // Stop the timer from ticking.
       myClickWaitTimer.Stop();

       ((ICommand)DataContext).Execute("DoubleLeftClickProj");
       e.Handled = true;
   }

   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       myClickWaitTimer.Start();
   }

   private static void mouseWaitTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       myClickWaitTimer.Stop();

       // Handle Single Click Actions
       ((ICommand)context).Execute("SingleLeftClick");
   }
   ```